# I can't get a MongoDB "find" query to work using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mongodb

I am trying to make a frontend for a MongoDB database using C#. 
So far I have managed to get the connection and the insert method to work. 
But I'm stuck with the find method as I am new to C# and .net in general.

```
public void FindDocument(string query) {
            BsonDocument QueryDoc = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(query);
            MongoCursor result = Collection.FindAs(QueryDoc);
```

The last line is giving me a really long error:

```
the type arguments for the method 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAs<TDocument>'(MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery) can't be inferrred from usage. Try to specify the type arguments explicitly)
```

I'm completely lost here. If it is necessary, I can post the entire class here. Let me know. I'm using this driver by the way: CSharpDriver-1.10.0 from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindAs` expects you tell what *type* (class) you're expecting, so you'd have to call something like `Collection.FindAs<MyClass>(query)`.

However, your code seems a little more complex than necessary. It's usually easier to work with your classes directly and use `QueryBuilders` to create the query (they can also be passed to other methods as `IMongoQuery`).

```
class MyClass {
   public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
   public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   // ...
}

var coll = mongoDb.GetCollection<MyClass>("MyClass");
var result = coll.Find(Query<MyClass>.EQ(p => p.UserId == someId));

// result is now a MongoCursor<MyClass>
```

Also, please note that a completely new, async-aware version of the C# driver, is already in beta (currently 2.0.0-beta4). The interface has changed *completely*, so if you're starting now, it's probably easier to (only) learn the new interface.

Comment: I changed my code to this: `public void FindDocument(string query) {
            var result = Collection.Find(Query<Entry>.EQ(p => p.TERM == query));`

My docs are shaped like this (I'm making a dictionary):

{TERM: "Objecto-Oriented Programming", DEFINITION:"A programming paradigm"}

I have a class exaclty like the one you provided (but with the appropriate fields) as MyClass. 

Now it's giving me a different error: It's telling me there is no Find method. I do ctrl+spacebar and only FIndAs and its relatives appear. If I use it, the same error appears: can't be inferred from usage, etc.

Comment: I decided to follow mnemosyn's idea and wait for the new mongo driver. The new API s certainly simpler. Thaks for your answer :)